# ¿Cómo configurar los bindings de Ninject para este escenario?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Tengo una duda sobre Ninject, pero antes de ir directamente a la pregunta, explicaré el escenario general.

Tengo una interfaz Business llamada ITest__Business y su implementación Test__Business. Esta clase depende de 3 interfaces: ITest__Repository, ITest2__Repository y IConnectionUtil.
Las interfaces ITest__Repository, ITest2__Repository y IConnectionUtil tienen clases que las implementan con nombre por defecto (Test__Repository, Test2__Repository y ConnectionUtil respectivamente).

Estas clases de dominio representan entidades de negocio con dependencias de clases de repositorio y un utilitario de conexión para manejar el abrir y cerrar la conexión con base de datos.
La clase business depende de ambos repositorys y de un connectionutil. El connectionutil creado dentro del business es compartido por los 2 repositorys (para que tanto el negocio como los repositorys manejen una sola conexion con BD).

Este es el código de lo mencionado anteriormente:

```
public interface ITest__Business {
    TablaUno ManageTablaUno(TablaUno tablaUno);
    IConnectionUtil ConnectionUtil {get; }
    IConnectionUtil ConnectionUtil2 {get; }
}
public class Test__Business : ITest__Business {
    private IConnectionUtil connUtil1;
    private ITest__Repository repo1;
    private ITest2__Repository repo2;
    public Test__Business(IConnectionUtil connUtil1, ITest__Repository repo1, ITest2__Repository repo2) {
        this.connUtil1 = connUtil1;
        this.repo1 = repo1;
        this.repo2 = repo2;
    }

    public TablaUno ManageTablaUno(TablaUno tablaUno){
       using (var scope = new TransactionScope()) {
           // Metodos de repo1 y repo2 dentro de transaccion.
           //...
       }
    }

public interface ITest__Repository {
    IConnectionUtil ConnectionUtil { get; }
    TablaUno ManageTablaUno(TablaUno tablaUno);
}
public class Test__Repository : BaseRepository, ITest__Repository {
    public Test__Repository(IConnectionUtil connectionUtil) : base(connectionUtil) {
        // El connectionUtil se pasa a la base para recuperar el DbConnection.
    }

    public TablaUno ManageTablaUno(TablaUno tablaUno) {
        // Invocación a stored procedure con la conexion de la clase base.
    }
}

public interface ITest2__Repository {/*Metodos propios*/}
public class Test2__Repository : BaseRepository, ITest2__Repository {
     // Lógica similar a Test_Repository.
}

public interface IConnectionUtil {
    DbConnection Connection { get; }
    void Open();
    void Close();
}
public class ConnectionUtil : IConnectionUtil, IDisposable {
    private SqlConnection connection;

    public ConnectionUtil(string connStringKey) {
        var connString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connStringKey].ConnectionString;
        connection = new SqlConnection(connString);
    }

    public DbConnection Connection => connection;

    public void Open() {
        try {
            connection.Open();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Excepcion en ConnectionUtil.Open: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }

    public void Close() {
        try {
            if (connection != null && connection.State == ConnectionState.Open) {
                connection.Close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Excepcion en ConnectionUtil.Close: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }

    /*Logica Disposable*/
}
```

Y mi configuración del módulo Ninject:

```
public class ConsoleModule : NinjectModule {
    public override void Load() {
        Kernel.Bind<IConnectionUtil>().To<ConnectionUtil>().InCallScope().WithConstructorArgument("connStringKey", "Test1Connection");
        Kernel.Bind<ITest__Repository>().To<Test__Repository>().InTransientScope();
        Kernel.Bind<ITest2__Repository>().To<Test2__Repository>().InTransientScope();
        Kernel.Bind<ITestDb2__Repository>().To<TestDb2__Repository>().InTransientScope();
        Kernel.Bind<ITest__Business>().To<Test__Business>().InTransientScope();
    }
}
```

Posteriormente se solicitó que se agregue al business un nuevo repository (repo3) y un nuevo connectionutil (connUtil2). El connUtil2 que se crea en el business es diferente al connUtil1 (tiene su propia conexion a una bd diferente) y debe ser compartido con el nuevo repository (repo3). Esto para lograr interactuar con 2 bases de datos diferentes.

Para lograr esto, he creado una clase attribute ConnectionAttribute que tiene un constructor que setea la cadena de conexion que se leerá del archivo .config.
Este atributo se debe agregar a connUtil2 y repo3 con la nueva cadena de conexion "Test2Connection", indicando que estos están relacionados. A repo1, repo2 y connUtil1 no se les agrega este atributo, de manera que al momento de resolver las dependencias, si estos target no tienen dicho atributo, se usará cadena de conexion original "Test1Connection".

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class ConnectionAttribute : Attribute {
    public string ConnectionString { get; private set; }

    public ConnectionAttribute(string connectionString) {
        ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }
}

public class Test__Business : ITest__Business {
    // Se ignora propiedades y metodos por brevedad.
    public Test__Business(IConnectionUtil connUtil1, [Connection("Test2Connection")] IConnectionUtil connUtil2,
        ITest__Repository repo1, ITest2__Repository repo2, [Connection("Test2Connection")] ITestDb2__Repository repo3) {
        this.connUtil1 = connUtil1;
        this.connUtil2 = connUtil2;
        this.repo1 = repo1;
        this.repo2 = repo2;
        this.repo3 = repo3;
    }
}
```

Actualicé también el modulo ninject:

```
public class ConsoleModule : NinjectModule {
    private IList<string> scopeList = new List<string>();

    public ConsoleModule() {
        foreach (ConnectionStringSettings connstr in WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings) {
            scopeList.Add(connstr.Name);
        }
    }

    //public override void Load() {
    //    Kernel.Bind<IConnectionUtil>().To<ConnectionUtil>().InCallScope().WithConstructorArgument("connStringKey", "Test1");
    //    Kernel.Bind<ITest__Repository>().To<Test__Repository>().InTransientScope();
    //    Kernel.Bind<ITest2__Repository>().To<Test2__Repository>().InTransientScope();
    //    Kernel.Bind<ITestDb2__Repository>().To<TestDb2__Repository>().InTransientScope();
    //    Kernel.Bind<ITest__Business>().To<Test__Business>().InTransientScope();
    //}

    public override void Load() {
        Kernel.Bind<IConnectionUtil>().To<ConnectionUtil>().InScope(context => {
            var scopeCadena = string.Empty;
            if (context.Request.Target.Member.DeclaringType.Name.Contains("Repository")) {
                var pr = context.Request.ParentRequest.Target.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ConnectionAttribute), false);
                var cadena = pr.Length == 0 ? "Test1" : ((ConnectionAttribute)pr[0]).ConnectionString;
                scopeCadena = scopeList.Single(x => x == cadena);
            }

            if (context.Request.Target.Member.DeclaringType.Name.Contains("Business")) {
                var attrs = context.Request.Target.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ConnectionAttribute), false);
                var cadena = attrs.Length == 0 ? "Test1" : ((ConnectionAttribute)attrs[0]).ConnectionString;
                scopeCadena = scopeList.Single(x => x == cadena);
            }

            return scopeCadena;
        }).WithConstructorArgument("connStringKey", context => {
            var cadena = "Test1";
            if (context.Request.Target.Member.DeclaringType.Name.Contains("Repository")) {
                var pr = context.Request.ParentRequest.Target.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ConnectionAttribute), false);
                cadena = pr.Length == 0 ? "Test1" : ((ConnectionAttribute)pr[0]).ConnectionString;
            }

            if (context.Request.Target.Member.DeclaringType.Name.Contains("Business")) {
                var attrs = context.Request.Target.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ConnectionAttribute), false);
                cadena = attrs.Length == 0 ? "Test1" : ((ConnectionAttribute)attrs[0]).ConnectionString;
            }

            return cadena;
        });

        Kernel.Bind<ITest__Repository>().To<Test__Repository>().InTransientScope();
        Kernel.Bind<ITestDb2__Repository>().To<TestDb2__Repository>();
        Kernel.Bind<ITest__Business>().To<Test__Business>();
    }
```

Esto parece funcionar bien, pero el problema es que cada vez que llamo a Kernel.Get<ITest__Business>, los connUtil1 y connUtil2 se comparten entre business, y lo que necesito es que estos estén relacionados al ámbito del negocio, creando nuevos connUtil1 y connUtil2 con cada instancia de negocio.

¿Cómo debo hacer las configuraciones de ninject para este nuevo caso?